# Is this article on Nero even remotely accurate?

Tags: roman-empire

[Weev's livejournal](http://weev.livejournal.com/373187.html) Some of the problems in this article is that while Nero was blond and blue eyed it ignored that he was spotted and potbellied not to mention a known sexual deviant. 
The claims in this article is that he was a strong supporter of Democracy...is this even accurate?

Comment: Is Suetonius and his description of Nero's physical appearance trustworthy? He wrote about Nero 50 years after Nero's death and, even then, there were other historians making claims of revisionism and bias against Nero.

Comment: Also - the article doesn't claim he created Democracy - but that he was "was a visionary of Western democracy, implementing reforms"... although, I think that's a long bow to draw in the context

Comment: 'Is Suetonius and his description of Nero's physical appearance trustworthy? He wrote about Nero 50 years after Nero's death and, even then, there were other historians making claims of revisionism and bias against Nero" Oh...well that explains alot...

Comment: @HorusKol Well, Quellenforschung never ends, of course, but on this particular score, I think Suetonius can be believed about physical appearance. 50 years is not such a long time for a famous man's looks to be forgotten and it's not clear what would Suetonius gain by lying on such verifiable (by his readers!, not us) matters. I'm not saying that he would not have or did not manipulate his accounts in other ways, but then it'd be all the more important to him to establish credibility by getting stuff like appearance right.

Comment: P.S. Suetonius was a high court official so he would certainly be in a position to know.

Answer (score 6):

This article lacks any sense. To start, it is impossible to tell someone's eye color from a bust, furthermore as discussed [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/30775/10330), the accuracy of historical busts is also questionable.

Secondly, there is no evidence that the drafter's of the constitution were inspired "spiritually" by Nero in their writing of the eighth amendment.

There are many other issues within this document from simple misunderstanding to what comes across as active deception. In conclusion, this article should be ignored.

Comment: "it is impossible to tell someone's eye color from a bust" unless it was originally painted and there are some pigments that remain, even if we can't see it.

Comment: @AChildofGod Yes, that is true. However, I don't believe that was the case with this bust.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this article/rant/blogpost is deep in "not even wrong" territory. I shudder to think of the miseducation its author must have received.